# If $b = c \times a$ and $c = a \times b$, and length $b$ = length $c$, $a$ is a unit vector.

Tags: vector-spaces

If $\vec b = \vec c \times \hat a\,$  and $\,\vec c = \hat a \times \vec b\,$, and  $|\vec b|$ = $|\vec c|$.

Assuming $\vec b \ne 0$.

I have managed to prove $\vec a$, $\vec b$ and $\vec c$ are orthogonal, but not much else.

Help appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What do we have to prove? That $\hat a$ is a unit vector?
If you have already showed they are perpendicular, you can just use the formula $|\vec a \times \vec b|=|\vec a||\vec b|\sin\frac{\Pi}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
  b \times c &= b \times (a \times b)\\
     &= \bigl(b \cdot b\bigr)a - \bigl((c\times a) \cdot a\bigr)b\\
     &= |b|^2 a 
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*} 
  b \cdot c &= (c \times a)\cdot c\\
            &= 0,
\end{align*}
hence $|b \times c| = |b||c| = |b|^2$ and therefore
\[
  |a| = \frac{|b \times c|}{|b|^2} = 1.
\]

Answer (score 0):

Note also that $u \times (v\times w)=(u\cdot w)v-(u\cdot v)w$

And $a\cdot c=a\cdot (a\times b)=0$

Apply this to $c=a\times b=a\times (c\times a)=|a|^2c-(a\cdot c)a=|a|^2c$

It looks as though the comment by Ali is the solution intended, as it can be carried through without knowing the identity for the triple product, but does use the information that $b$ and $c$ have the same length, which turns out to be unnecessary for the triple product solution.

Note that $c$ is non-zero since $b$ is non-zero and $b = c\times a$.